# ERROR in multi main Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'bundle.js'

Tags: webpack, bundle

I am trying to add webpack to an existing project built with the https://cosmicjs.com/ platform. I have included an early stage Webpack.config.js file with the following code:

```
var path = require('path');

entry: path.resolve(__dirname, '/src/index.js'),
instead of:
entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.js'),

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',
  entry: './app.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/public/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.js']
  },
  node: {
    console: 'empty',
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty'
  }
};
```

Within my project root I have an `app.js` file and a `public\` and `views\` folders. Inside `views\`I have an `index.html` where I call the bundle script: `<script src="bundle.js"></script>`. The bundle.js file is generated inside the `public\` folder as per the config file above. However when I do:`webpack ./app.js bundle.js` in terminal I get the following error:

```
Hash: f1c7ed9b1e871bc9daf0
Version: webpack 1.13.3
Time: 2112ms
    Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
bundle.js  1.31 MB       0  [emitted]  main
   [0] multi main 52 bytes {0} [built] [1 error]
   [1] ./app.js 544 bytes {0} [built]
    + 128 hidden modules

WARNING in ./~/express/lib/view.js
Critical dependencies:
78:29-56 the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./~/express/lib/view.js 78:29-56

ERROR in multi main
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'bundle.js' in /Users/elby/git/histamyn/cosmicapp-histamyn
 @ multi main
```

I feel like I am doing something really obvious that I cannot see. It is difficult to add webpack to an existing dynamic project so there may be a conflict somewhere down the line. my `app.js` file contains the following code:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var hogan = require('hogan-express')
app.engine('html', hogan)
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 3000))
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public/'))
var Cosmic = require('cosmicjs')
var bucket_slug = process.env.COSMIC_BUCKET || 'stellar'
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  Cosmic.getObjects({ bucket: { slug: bucket_slug } }, function(err, response) {
    res.locals.cosmic = response;
    res.render('index.html')
  })
});
app.listen(app.get('port'))
console.log('app loaded')
```

And runs the views/index.html under `http://localhost:3000/`